# Generate user friendly report from Unit Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, nunit, mstest

So I'm working with Xamarin UITest and my manager is asking if there is a way we can run the test cases and generate a user friendly report (Very vague, I know). So my question is there a framework that can do this? Run some tests (MSTest or NUnit) and generate a report to some log file for management? I'm really just looking for a way for management to run and see the results of these tests without using the test explorer. Just wondering...Thanks

Comment: Run the tests as part of CI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code coverage report generated in VisualStudio- 
[image]

[Using Code Coverage to Determine How Much Code is being Tested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx)

Comment: Thanks,  I'm really just looking for a way for management to run and see the results of these tests without using the test explorer.

Comment: Do you have a build server?

Comment: Yes we have a server to do automated builds

Comment: You need a machine with Visual studio installed to run these reports. Manager cant run in his machine. Since you already have a build server, along with the build you can also generate these unit test reports and store it in the shared folder which the manager can access. He will have the latest data.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks. Just seeing what my options are here.